# The bias of the bootstrap estimator

Tags: cross-validation, bootstrap, bias

From what I gather, a Bootstrap estimation of the generalization error for a ML procedure is **optimistically biased**, e.g.:

- [What is the .632+ rule in bootstrapping?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96739/what-is-the-632-rule-in-bootstrapping)
- [Why is bootstrapping called an "optimistic" model validator? When should I use bootstrapping or cross validation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386545/why-is-bootstrapping-called-an-optimistic-model-validator-when-should-i-use-b)
- [Cross-validation or bootstrapping to evaluate classification performance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71184/cross-validation-or-bootstrapping-to-evaluate-classification-performance)

As far as I understand it, the source of the optimism is that with bootstrap we are **testing** on much of the data that we are training with.

I presume the bias depends on what we are estimating, so there is **no** universal formula for it (e.g. MSE of a particular regressor). Is this correct?

If so, are there still any known **universal** lower or upper **theoretical bounds** of the bias of the bootstrap estimator? Or does it fully depend on the generalization error that we are estimating and e.g. the underlying ML model?